# How to view user privileges using windows cmd?

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, privileges, wmic

I am trying to view the user privileges using the command prompt in Windows. 
User account & User privileges such as:

```
SeBatchLogonRight
SeDenyBatchLogonRight
SeInteractiveLogonRight
SeDenyInteractiveLogonRight
SeServiceLogonRight
SeDenyServiceLogonRight
SeNetworkLogonRight
SeDenyNetworkLogonRight
```

I tried using `ntrights` but it's not working. I can't use any tool as I am trying to create an automated script for an OS audit.

Comment: When you say ntrights is "not working", what exactly goes wrong?

Comment: Assuming it does not necessarily have to be cmd.exe: maybe you can do this wih powershell? if so, maybe ask the question again here, this time with "powershell" tag.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'd start with:

```
secedit /export /areas USER_RIGHTS /cfg OUTFILE.CFG
```

Then examine the line for the relevant privilege. However, the problem now is that the accounts are listed as SIDs, not usernames.

Comment: Worth a mention... To find out which privs the current user has, use WHOAMI /PRIV.

Comment: More details on secedit [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490997.aspx).

Comment: Would be good if you could explain the details of this command better. I didn't get any sensible output from that on Win8.1.

Comment: This is pretty horrible to use but it works well. After exporting the template using Simon's command above, you can import it again using: Secedit /configure /db secedit.sdb /cfg outfile.cfg /quiet /areas USER_RIGHTS

Comment: I'm not sure whether this will work for rights that are acquired indirectly, e.g., via group membership.

Answer (score 63):

You can use the following commands:

```
whoami /priv
whoami /all
```

For more information, check [whoami @ technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771299.aspx).

Comment: Note that it's only available out of the box since Vista. In XP, it's in the "Windows XP SP2 Support Tools" download.

Comment: This is the best answer.   IMHO Anyone still using XP needs to upgrade

Comment: Note that this will work for privileges but not for rights.

Answer (score 24):

Mark Russinovich wrote a terrific tool called AccessChk that lets you get this information from the command line. No installation is necessary.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb664922.aspx

For example:

```
accesschk.exe /accepteula -q -a SeServiceLogonRight
```

Returns this for me:

```
IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool
IIS APPPOOL\Classic .NET AppPool
NT SERVICE\ALL SERVICES
```

By contrast, `whoami /priv` and `whoami /all` were missing some entries for me, like `SeServiceLogonRight`.

Comment: Tremendous -- not least, allows verification of the right for another user without impersonation with RUNAS.

Comment: Yes, `whoami /priv` will only work for privileges, not rights, because it works by examining the current user token.  Rights are only used at logon time, so there's no need for them to be kept in the token.

Comment: In later versions of acceschk, `-q` has been replaced with `-nobanner`

Answer (score 2):

Go to command prompt and enter the command,

```
net user <username>
```

Will show your local group memberships.

If you're on a domain, use **localgroup** instead:

```
net localgroup Administrators or net localgroup [Admin group name]
```

Check the list of local groups with localgroup on its own.

```
net localgroup
```

Comment: I need the detailed privileges of all users as i am logged in as admin... not the basic user info...

Comment: Group membership is a different concept than user privileges.   Use `whoami /priv`

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an open source tool that might be of assistance:

https://github.com/Bill-Stewart/PrivMan

To view a specific account (user or group) privileges/rights, you would use:

```
PrivMan -a username --list
```

The output will be the list of privileges/rights (e.g., `SeServiceLogonRight`, etc.) directly assigned to that account.

Answer (score -4):

Use `whoami /priv` command to list all the user privileges.

Comment: You should not duplicate existing answers, especially that there already is [a more complete answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18398600/868014).