# I am not able to create msi setup using installshield for self hosted console application

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, windows-installer

[image]I have created self-hosted WCF service using Console application. I have created msi using Installshield but when I am installing setup it will stuck and after some time failed to setup.

I have added log in code and found that on the line of hosting WCF service it was going to stuck and throw an error.

Any Idea how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Hey Fildor, you can see image of error I receive.

Comment: Do you run that installer with Admin privileges?

Comment: yes. Even I created this app using admin previlage

Comment: It is possible to run an MSI file without admin rights, but I assume you have set the field in the release view to require admin rights?

Comment: How can I set it? I am creating setup using Install Shield?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Service Install***: Can you install and run it manually? You must install with **admin rights**, if you specify a user account to run the service it must have the [**"log on as a service" privilege**](https://ss64.com/nt/ntrights.html) (check by running **`secpol.msc`** or [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11607389/how-to-view-user-privileges-using-windows-cmd)), the file you install must actually be a **proper service** - obviously - I sometimes mix up my test executables with the service binary. Ever forget? Happens to me :-).

***Logging***: Get yourself a proper log file first of all:

```
msiexec.exe /i "Setup.msi" /L*V "C:\Setup.log"
```

Or in silent mode:

```
msiexec.exe /i "Setup.msi" /QN /L*V "C:\Setup.log"
```

Some more information on Logging:

- [**Installsite.org on logging**](http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/msifaq/a/1022.htm)
- [Event logging, etc...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49983606/visual-studio-installer-fails-on-aspnetdiagnosticpack-msi/49987350#49987350)
- [Interpreting MSI log files, etc...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49028367/129130)

---

***Credentials***: Just adding that there are several **built-in accounts** you can use to run the service:

- [The difference between the 'Local System' account and the 'Network Service' account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510170/the-difference-between-the-local-system-account-and-the-network-service-acco/510225#510225)
- And there is the new concept of ["managed service accounts"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/access-control/service-accounts). [Step-by-Step](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/dd548356(v=ws.10)).
- And finally ["group managed service account"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/hh831782(v=ws.11)).

Comment: I have created a log and I came up with that while installing all codes are running and my self hosted service is also hosted successfully and running but I noticed that this whole process is going in recursive mode and at last it is getting stopped. Why it is happening? Even my exe is also running and installed.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you are saying. Maybe the service fails to start properly? Are you installing via the MSI tables for service installation or are you running some custom action commands? You can dump your log file somewhere if you want us to have a quick look. Maybe even github?

Comment: Lobbing you a link with [service FAQ](https://www.coretechnologies.com/WindowsServices/FAQ.html).

Comment: Great, do let us know what you find out. You can add your own answer and set it accepted so others see what you found. My still experimental site [installdude.com](http://www.installdude.com) has more links for deployment matters. For example: Under **"Debugging"** (black square towards top), click the **"Essential Service Tools"** link.